# What is wrong in my calculation of the values of $a$ for which $f(x) = ax$ is an automorphism of the group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am given the function:

$$f:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \hspace{2.5cm} f(x) = ax$$

And I have to find the set of values of $a$ for which the function $f$ is an automorphism of the group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$.

Now I know that a function is an automorphism if the function is a morphism and the function is one-to-one. The following:

$$f(x + y) = a(x + y) = ax + ay$$

$$f(x) + f(y) = ax + ay$$

clearly shows that the function is indeed a morphism of the group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$. On top of this, for the function to be one to one, the function cannot be constant, so we have that $a \ne 0$. So I concluded that the answer is:

$$a \in \mathbb{Z} ^*$$

But my textbook claims that the right answer is actually:

$$a \in \{ -1, 1 \}$$

So what did I forget to consider? What's wrong?

Comment: An automorphism needs to be injective $\textbf{and surjective}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group. An automorphism is an isomorphism $\phi:G\to G$. In other words, an automorphism of $G$ is a map that satisfies the following:

1. it maps $G\to G$,
2. the map is a homomorphism,
3. the map is injective,
4. the map is surjective.

You forgot to check surjectivity.

Answer (score 1):

A homomorphism from $\Bbb Z$ is determined by $f(1)$, since $1$ is a generator.

To be surjective, $f$ must map $1$ to a generator.  $\Bbb Z$ has exactly two generators, $\pm1$.

Thus $x\to x$ and $x\to -x$ are the only possibilities.